# How can I count dynamically created objects using .length?

Tags: jquery

I know how to trigger events on such objects and also how to manipulate them using the `$(container).on('DOM event', 'p', function(){...` method. But, how can I count how many `p` elements I have including those not created dynamically using JQuery?

Comment: `$('p').length`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying. I have a list of DIV sent by the server, I count them using .lenght, I get 12. Through a JQuery I create more of these same DIVs, I count again and still have 12.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to atribute the class to the created elements.

Comment: What do divs have to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the length property on the jQuery object to get the number of elements (whatever element you specify , in this case a `<p>` tag) on the page.

```js
console.log($('p').length)

// inside a click handler
$(document).on('click', 'p', function(){
        console.log($('p').length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I am a para !</p>
<p>I am a para 1 !</p>
<p>I am a para 2 !</p>
<p>I am a para 3 !</p>
<p>I am a para 4 !</p>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying. I have a list of DIV sent by the server, I count them using .lenght, I get 12. Through a JQuery I create more of these same DIVs, I count again and still have 12.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you can loop through all elements of one type. Simply add a counter.
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$( "p" ).each(function( index ) 
{
  count++
})
```

Comment: Even if such items are created dynamically? I'm not sure. The problem is, you can do this using $(container).on('DOM event', 'p', function(){... But it depends on a event direcly related to the container.

Comment: If you want to count them before the DOM is created, you'll probably have to count them in your code behind. If you want to count afterwards, the code snippet should work. Generally, if you're creating code dynamically, you'd do it with code behind (at least I do). When creating new elements after the DOM is loaded, it can be more difficult obtaining those elements from code behind but you should be able to find them through javascript.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to atribute the class to the created elements.